# Rails Limit results based on Date Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have the following Strucuture in the database

```
db.slots.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ae8990bd521b2da7000003"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T05:03:12.345Z"),
    "day_from" : "Mon",
    "day_to" : "Sat",
    "doctor_clinic_id" : ObjectId("52ae8990bd521b2da7000004"),
    "evening_time_from" : 0,
    "evening_time_from_period" : "AM",
    "evening_time_to" : 0,
    "evening_time_to_period" : "AM",
    "morning_time_from" : 9,
    "morning_time_from_period" : "AM",
    "morning_time_to" : 2,
    "morning_time_to_period" : "PM",
    "store" : [
        ISODate("2013-12-13T09:00:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T09:15:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T09:30:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T09:45:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T10:00:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T10:15:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T10:30:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T10:45:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T11:00:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T11:15:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T11:30:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T11:45:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T12:00:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T12:15:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T12:30:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T12:45:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T13:00:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T13:15:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T13:30:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-13T13:45:00Z"),
........
.....
..
        ISODate("2013-12-25T13:15:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-25T13:30:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-25T13:45:00Z"),
        ISODate("2013-12-25T14:00:00Z")
    ],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-12-16T05:03:12.345Z")
}
```

**I want to only fetch the content of the Store which has the date of Today and the next five days.**

When  i try the following i get a single slot back

```
slots.where(:store.gte => Date.today)
```

Results

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria selector: {"doctor_clinic_id"=>"52ae8990bd521b2da7000004", "store"=>{"$gte"=>Mon, 16 Dec 2013}} options: {} class: Slot embedded: false>
```

slot.rb

```
class Slot
  include Mongoid::Document
field :store, type: Array

  belongs_to :clinic
end
```

`slot.store.where(:store.gte => Date.today)` resulting one output like above..!!!

Comment: What you see there is the criteria, i.e the query. Could you paste what you receive when you do something like slots.where(:store.gte => Date.today).to_a ?

Comment: for above command it display as "undefined method `__bson_dump__' for Mon, 16 Dec 2013:Date", So we need to take out .to_a display as result "#<Mongoid::Criteria selector: {"doctor_clinic_id"=>"52ae8990bd521b2da7000004", "store"=>{"$gte"=>Mon, 16 Dec 2013}} options: {} class: Slot embedded: false> "

Comment: could you paste your models; Slot.rb and related

Comment: yes my slot.rb is like above snippet.

Comment: Did the answer helped you or do you need more/different information?

Comment: Yes i need different approach!!!

Answer (score 1):

First: What you are trying to achieve is called projection in MongoDB, which is used when you want to retrieve only certain fields from an element. Indeed what you are trying to do is retrieve certain elements from an array field (See [Mongodb projection positional](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/))

In mongo you try something like this:

```
query={}
projection = {day_from:1, day_to:1} //Retrieve only _id, day_from and day_to fields
db.slots.find(query,projection).pretty()
```

[Mongodb projection positional](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) is what you would need but the documentation says that it only returns the first element that matches the query.

So I guess that you cannot directly with mongo. I recommend you to try a different approach like a formatter and virtual attributes. Something similar to:

```
class Slot
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :store, type: Array

  def with_dates_after date
    self.virtual_store= self.store.select{|elem| elem >= date} 
  end

  def virtual_store= arg_arr
    @_virtual_store = arg_arr
  end

  def virtual_store
   @_virtual_store ||= []
  end

end
```